# How to delete the commands that pop up after opening the terminal in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: bash, bashrc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjCYt.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayynj.png)Every time I open a new terminal tab, some startup files try to send commands. And I get this:

[image: terminal showing startup commands errors]

What should I do? It's a bit annoying.

Comment: You have added those words in your bashrc (or similar) files. Can you add the output of `grep Reading ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_aliases` to your question, please?

Comment: I added it now. As for the bashrc, I checked and there is nothing strange, but I was changing path a lot and here is the result that may be the problem.

Comment: looks like you piped output from some command into your .bashrc. Go edit those files (and whichever file the first image is from) and take out all the lines that start with `Reading` and `Building` (and anything else that doesn't belong there).

Answer (score 0):

Yep. I have solved it. Thank you guys in the comments. The problem was just that the commands regarding the path which didn't exist were written in the bashrc file. I deleted them and that's it. Clean new terminal tabs.